# "leya" é uma variante de "leia", verbo ler?

Tags: ortografia, português-europeu

Vejo um [**cartaz**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLCCAo4i87I) em um rua (de Coimbra?) onde está escrita a palavra "leya".  Trata-se de uma variante ortográfica do verbo ler conjugado no imperativo, ou trata-se de um erro?

Comment: Será [E(ditora) Leya](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeYa)?

Comment: Sim, trata-se de um trocadilho publicitário. O local onde os músicos tocaram é o cruzamento entre a Rua Ferreira Borges e a Rua do Arco Almedina ([veja o local no Google Maps](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@40.2089446,-8.4291409,3a,60y,179.62h,76.49t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sAr2ee61wxzO0eIASXVA7zA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)). Neste mesmo endereço há [a loja LeYa de Coimbra](https://www.lojj.pt/leya-coimbra/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, é só um nome de uma marca.

A [LeYa](http://leya.pt/pt/) é uma mega-editora lusófona. Tem presença pelo menos em Portugal, Brasil, Angola e Moçambique.

Esse vídeo é na Rua Ferreira Borges 79, 3000-363 Coimbra.
Aí estava a [Coimbra Editora](http://coimbraeditora.net), que entretanto mudou para o [Centro Comercial do Arnado](http://coimbraeditora.net/livrarias.html).
Pensei que fosse aí que estivesse o cartaz da LeYa...

Mas de acordo com a pesquisa do Seninha, aí é agora [uma loja da LeYa](https://www.lojj.pt/leya-coimbra/).

Comment: Mas, de qualquer forma, a letra ⟨y⟩ já existiu produtivamente no português para representar a semi-vogal /i/, como em *"[janeyro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/janeyro#Old_Portuguese), [fevreyro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fevreyro#Old_Portuguese), [mayo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mayo#Old_Portuguese)"*. Mas ainda assim, nessa época "leia" era "lea". A semi-vogal só apareceu posteriormente para quebrar o hiato. Mas talvez durante o período de transição fonética, escreviam "leya" como uma variante. Por exemplo, "feya" já ocorria em vez de "fea" (feia), indicando a quebra do hiato.

Comment: Muito bem exposto! Um exemplo claro desses y é o nome de família, raro mas conhecido, "Feyo" - e.g. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvador_Barata_Feyo

Comment: Não sei por quanto tempo **feya** existiu após **fea** até ser substituído por **feia**, acho que isso vale uma pergunta. No corpus do Wikisources, ["feya"](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search="feya") é raro, mas ["fea"](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search="fea") é comum. N'Os Lvsiadas há cinco casos de *"fea"* vs. dois de *"feya"* (deve ter sido escrito durante a transição). Quanto ao verbo ler, não achei **"leya"**, mas achei **"leyo"** ([oitava linha de baixo pra cima](https://pt.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search="feo")). E que nome esse do cidadão! Ainda bem que é raro!

Comment: @Seninha e ANeves, eu tenho lido autores do sXIX na grafia original, e eles só usam o *y* em palavras que o tinham na língua original (ou que eles pensassem que tinham), *abysmo, hypothese, mystico*. Depois das reformas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil, o *y* passou a ser usado apenas em nomes de origem estrangeira e seus derivados (keynesianismo).